# best way to find nested object in Immutable.js Map

Tags: javascript, nested, immutable.js

I have an Immutable Map structure, which maps a presentationId to a slideId to a map with properties of the slide, amongst which is 'opened', like so:

```
//maps a chapterId to a pageId
var map = Map(fromJS({
    123: {
        22: {
            slideId: 22,
            presentationId: 123,
            opened: 1
        }
          23: {
            slideId: 23,
            presentationId: 123,
            opened: 0
        }
    }
}));
```

What is the best way to grab / find the slide which has opened === 1?

I have this, which works, but I think there must be a better / nicer way with less lines of code?

```
var openSlide;
map.some((slideMap, presentationId) => {
    openSlide = slideMap.find(slide => {
        return parseInt(slide.get('opened')) === 1;
    });
    return openSlide ? true : false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way would be use `.reduce`, thanks that you don't need to have variable outside scope what is better if it comes to readability. Instead `find` in this case `some` would be better because you don't need to parse your found object to boolean it would be already parsed.

```
const openSlide = map.reduce((acc, slideMap) => {
  return acc || slideMap.some(slide => {
    return parseInt(slide.get('opened')) === 1
  })
}, false)
```